# Azure Data Factory concating syntax

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to run a pipeline that results a select with where be the system triggername system output.

I've tried to use :

[image]

```
@concat(concat(concat(concat('select * from ',item().DB_CARGA,'.',item().SC_CARGA,'.',item().tb_carga, 'where ' ,item().DS_CARGA ,'=', string(pipeline().TriggerName)))))
```

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Could anyone help me with the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and got similar error when I used your syntax.

[image]

In your dynamic expression, **there should be a space between `table name` and `where`** and also **trigger name should be enclosed in single quotes**.

Please go through the below procedure to resolve the error.

First, I have a lookup activity which will give database name, table name and SQL table column(trigger column name). Give this to Foreach.

[image]

I have created sample tables with `trigger_column` column and gave some values.

[image]

In pipeline I have created trigger with same name `mytrigger`. Inside Foreach for my demo `I have used lookup query`. You can use your activity as per the requirement.

[image]

**Dynamic content:**

You can do this with single `concat` function.

```
@concat('select * from ',item().database,'.',item().table_name, ' where ' ,item().trigger_name ,'=','''',string(pipeline().TriggerName),'''')
```

This will give the SQL query like this when Executed.

[image]

**Output when triggered:**

[image]

Comment: "thanks" a lot . Your solution worked very well for me!